# Is there a way to delete an Apex Class using the Salesforce DX CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx

Is there a way to delete an Apex Class using the Salesforce DX CLI, without using the metadata API and a package.xml file (in the same way you can create an Apex class)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can now use the `force:source:delete` option to delete metadata from non-scratch orgs. See the documentation for full usage, but here's an example:

```
sfdx force:source:delete -m ApexClass:SomeClassName -r
```

For scratch orgs, delete the local files, then use the normal push command:

```
sfdx force:source:push
```

## Original Answer

If, and only if, you're using scratch orgs, deleting a class in your repo and then using force:source:push should result in a deletion of the components that have been physically removed from the repository. For non-scratch-org deployments, you still need to use the normal force:mdapi:deploy function with a destructiveChanges.xml file.

Comment: sfdx force:source:delete works also on Sandboxes but not in a Production

Comment: @benahm No, but you can use unlocked packages, which would be the ideal way to deploy to production.

Answer (score 7):

SFDX Team says they are working on implementing that,
but for the moment, you will need to use metadata API as follows:

1. Create a new folder in your SFDX project, and call it "destructiveChanges" (or whatever).
2. Create a `destructiveChanges.xml` file in that folder.  The contents of that file will be in the standard package.xml manifest format, but it will be the stuff you want to delete.  Here is example contents.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
>     <types>
>         <members>SomeTriggerToDelete</members>
>         <name>ApexTrigger</name>
>     </types>
>     <types>
>         <members>SomeClassToDelete</members>
>         <name>ApexClass</name>
>     </types>
> </Package>
> ```

3. In that same folder, create a `package.xml` file (contents below).  It will be almost empty.  The `<version>` value needs to be the same as `sourceApiVersion` in the `sfdx-project.json` file in your project.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
>     <version>48.0</version>
> </Package>
> ```

4. From the project's root directory, run the following command, replacing destinationOrgAlias with whatever destination org is for the deletion, and replacing "SomeSimpleTestClassName" with any test class from your org - the deploy requires some tests to run, so it doesn't matter which, as long as those tests pass.

`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d destructiveChanges -u destinationOrgAlias -l RunSpecifiedTests -r SomeSimpleTestClassName -g -w -1`

In this command:

`-d` is the directory name where the `destructiveChanges.xml` is located;

`-r` is the name of the test class to run;

`-g` is a flag to ignore warnings (can also put `--ignorewarnings`). If you don't set it, then when non-existing metadata is found in your `destructiveChanges.xml`, the deploy will fail. If you set it, deploy will simply skip invalid entries.

`-w` is the wait time - how long to wait before deploy times out.  `-1` means wait as long as needed.

Comment: This comment has been fantastic. We've used this method several times and it is great. We had one trip up where we had someone copy and paste the file name listed above `desctructiveChanges.xml` and then try to reference `destructiveChanges.xml` and fail because of the typo. That's an us problem but wondering if you could update to fix the typo for future peeps.

Comment: fixed!  thanks for the follow up

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, per the [CLI Reference Docs,](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm#cli_reference_force_apex) as of now there is no command that allows you to delete a class without using the metadata API. You have already mentioned using the metadata API/destructive changes, which is a good way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

If you try:
sfdx force:source:delete -m ApexClass:SomeClassName -r
sfdx force:source:push

You will indeed remove the class, but not its references (for instance, on profiles). Which means that the push will fail.

The best way to do this, it's to remove it on the org using the developer console. Then pull your changes into your repo.